# PHP named constant prints/concats as the variable name, not value

Tags: php, oscommerce

I have an old osCommerce site that was PHP4, now running on PHP5. Named constants defined with `define()` are being evaluated incorrectly:

```
$string = '<a href="http://www.oscommerce.com" target="_blank">' . BOX_ENTRY_SUPPORT_SITE . '</a><br>';
```

will show as `BOX_ENTRY_SUPPORT_SITE`, not the value placed in `BOX_ENTRY_SUPPORT_SITE`.

Something needs to be changed in `php.ini`?

Comment: Try to activate logging/displaying of notices in PHP. You'll probably see a diagnostic message telling you no constant `BOX_ENTRY_SUPPORT_SITE` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never ran into this problem when putting osCommerce sites on PHP5 from PHP4.

Most probably, that define isn't being `define()`'d correctly. The [default behaviour](http://codepad.org/bqiB9Rt6) (with error reporting relaxed) is to show the constant like that when it isn't found.

Comment: Aha, that's the missing bit of info, that the default behavior of undefined constant is to treat as a string. Error reporting was ~E_NOTICE as set in includes/application_top.php, so the php.ini change was ineffectual.  I also found in the application_top.php include where the language specific include code was COMMENTED OUT, and activating that solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

No, AFAIK constants behavior hasn't changed.

Most likely the constant is not defined; try to find where it's being defined and see if the file is being loaded by your script (ie: by require or include)

Comment: Also, activate error reporting, this should show something like "Undefined constant BOX_ENTRY_..., assuming "BOX_ENTRY_...".